# problem when using WhenEvent "StopIntegration" in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I am trying to solve some system of nonlinear differential equations by using `NDSolve`. I am looking for a particular shape of the solution which definitely excludes functions that at the initial point have a positive derivative. I want to use `WhenEvent` to stop the integration if the first derivative of the function is positive at the initial point (or actually a bit after it). However, when I try to do that, `WhenEvent` is never triggered. Here is a simplified problem where the same error occurs:

`NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[y'[10^{-6}] > 0, {"Stop Integration"}]}, y[t], {t, 0, 10}]`

I would expect that the integration would stop at t=10^{-6} because the derivative is definitely positive there, but actually, `NDSolve` continues to integrate up until t=10. What is the problem? Why can't `WhenEvent` register that the derivative is larger than zero and stop the integration at t=10^{-6}?

Comment: The proper event syntax according to the docs is `WhenEvent[t > 10^(-6), "StopIntegration"]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree about the "StopIntegration", my mistake, but it still doesn't work. The condition you put would stop integration whenever t > 10^(-6), but I am interested if the derivative at this point is larger than zero. Again, the example I gave is just to illustrate the actual problem which is more complicated.

Comment: Your event is still ill-defined. `WhenEvent[event && condition,..]` is triggered when the `event` "happens" (normally, flips from `False` to `True` but there are special cases) *provided* `condition` is true; otherwise, the event is ignored. In your example, which is the event and which is the condition, `t > 10^(-6)` / `y'[t] > 0`? Or is the event something else?

Comment: I thought `NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[t > 10^-6 && y'[t] > 0, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, 0, 10}]` would work like `NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[t > 10^-6 && y[t] > 0, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, 0, 10}]` does (no prime in event), but it doesn't.  Strange...

Comment: @ChrisK I was going to deal with that after knowing what the event is. It's because the highest order derivative is not treated as a state variable in an ODE. So only `t` and `y[t]` are available in `WhenEvent`. All variables are available in a DAE, so retry your code with the option `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, that works (although I try to avoid the DAE solver when possible, so maybe substituting in the definition of `y'[t]` from the differential equations is another [cumbersome] way to go).

Comment: @ChrisK I overstated the situation a bit. It does work with `y'[t]` in event (but not in the condition), in a regular ODE: `WhenEvent[y'[t] > 0 && t > 10^(-6), "StopIntegration"]`. (I don't know why. The docs are not particularly clear.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I was following the definition from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html where they say that WhenEvent[event, action], so I thought that y'[10^(-6)]>0 is the event, and that the action is "StopIntegration". Now I tried to write it like this. The point is to make the function stop at the point t=10^(-6). 

`Clear[y];`
`r = 10^(-4);`
`NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[y'[t] > 0 && t > 10^(-6), {r = t,"StopIntegration"}]}, y[t], {t, 0, 10}];`
`Plot[y[t] /. %, {t, 0, r}]`

But still, doesn't work.

Comment: On the face of it, `y'[10^(-6)]>0` is constant and doesn't change. An event is when a dynamic quantity passes some threshold. It needs to formally depend on `t`. I'm not sure whether the event you want is when the derivative changes from negative to positive (and `t` is big enough) or the event is when `t` crosses the time `10^(-6)` (and the derivative is positive). Second, `WhenEvent` can use only `y[t]` and `y'[t]`, not `y[2]` or `y[t - 1]`.  It's limited to the current value of the variables.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I understand. So my event should be y'[t]>0 because I am interested in the case when my function has a positive derivative at any point. 
`r = 1;`
`NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[y'[t] > 0, {r = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, y[t], {t, 0, 10}];`
`Plot[y[t] /. %, {t, 0, r}]`

From here I still see that the WhenEvent is not triggered because r is still 1 event after NDSolve.

Comment: An event represents a change, and `y'[t] > 0` represents the change of `y'[t]` from negative to positive. In your example `y'[t]` is always positive, so no change in sign and therefore no event ever occurs. The forms `f[t] > 0`, `f[t] < 0`, and `f[t] == 0` represent times at which `f[t]` changes sign, each in some specific way. The first two can be thought of as a time at which the inequality changes from `False` to `True`. The equation `f[t] == 0` has special semantics and represents a change in sign in either direction.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you, I now understand what is the problem. I will have to find a way to discard upfront functions that have a strictly positive first derivative from the beginning. Do you want to write this as the answer so I accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limitation that an event in `WhenEvent` cannot happen at the initial condition has been criticized on this site before.  Sometimes a user wants the event to happen on the initial step and sometimes not.  Whether or not this conflict was considered, the design choice sticks to the idea that an event is a change in state between steps that crosses a user-defined threshold. So an event can happen between step 0 and step 1, but not at step 0.

The OP would like an event that ends integration as soon as the derivative `y'[t]` is positive, including at the beginning.  It may appear the way to do this is to check the system at the initial condition before calling `NDSolve`.  One might think an event like `t > 10^(-6) && y'[t] > 0` might be a way to accomplish it. However, an event of the form `And[event, condition]` has a special semantics, which has also been criticized. It seems to be the case that the highest-order derivative `y'[t]` may appear in `event`, but errors ensue if it appears in `condition`.  However, there is a hack to get around this, but I think the most satisfying approach is to use the [`NDSolve` components](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html). Whatever the limitations of `WhenEvent`, one can get under the hood of `NDSolve` and the principal components are documented.  With a little programming, one can usually get the `NDSolve` suite to do what one wants.

There's one more restriction to deal with. The form `y'[t] > 0` has the special semantics of triggering an event if `y'[t]` changes from negative to positive.  It does not trigger an event if `y'[t]` changes from zero to positive, at least from step 0 to step 1.  I'm not sure what happens in the middle of integration, since it's virtually impossible to get a continuously changing quantity to land exactly at the value `0.`.  To get the desired event we use the logically equivalent `Not[y'[t] >= 0]`, which is treated strictly as a logical, boolean condition with no special interpretation.  ("Aaargh," I hear you say.)

Here is a modification of the OP's example that has four solutions, two which start with a positive `y'[t]`:

```
states = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{
    y'[t]^2 == y[t]^2, y[0]^2 == 1,
    WhenEvent[Not[y'[t] <= 0], "StopIntegration"]
    }, y, {t, 0, 10}];
Table[
 (* advance integration if y' is negative or zero *)
 If[NonPositive@First@NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[
     state@"SolutionData"["Active"], "X'"],
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, First@state@"VariableRanges"]
  ];
 NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state],
 {state, states}]
```

[image]

Here's the hacky way to get `WhenEvent` to stop on the first step (replace `$MinMachineNumber` by `10^-155` to avoid underflow warning):

```
NDSolve[{
  y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == 1,
  s[0] == 1,   (* user determines initial sign *)
  WhenEvent[y'[t] > 0, "StopIntegration"],
  WhenEvent[t > $MinMachineNumber && s[t] > 0,
   "StopIntegration",
   (* not necessary but reflects the intention: *)
   "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"]
  },
 y[t], {t, 0, 10},
 DiscreteVariables -> {s \[Element] {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

*Extension of the first method.*
For higher dimensional systems higher than a single first-order ODE, the derivative data, the `"X'"` component, will be a vector longer than 1.  One needs a way to find the particular derivative of interest, say `y'`.  The value of `state@"Variables"` indicates what the components of `state@"SolutionData"["Active"]` represent.

```
states = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{
    y''[t]^2 == y[t]^2, y'[0]^2 == 1, y[0] == 1,
    WhenEvent[Not[y'[t] <= 0], "StopIntegration"]
    }, y, {t, 0, 10}];
Table[
 (* advance integration if y' is negative or zero *)
 If[NonPositive@First@Extract[
     NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[
      state@"SolutionData"["Active"], "X'"],
     Position[
      NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[
       state@"Variables", "X'"],
      y'
      ]],
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, First@state@"VariableRanges"]
  ];
 NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state],
 {state, states}]
```

[image]

Here is an example where the distinction between `y'[t] > 0` and `Not[y'[t] >= 0]` makes a difference:

```
states = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{
    y''[t]^2 == y[t]^2, y'[0] == 0, y[0]^2 == 1,
    WhenEvent[Not[y'[t] <= 0], "StopIntegration"]
    }, y, {t, 0, 10}];
Table[
 If[NonPositive@First@Extract[
     NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[
      state@"SolutionData"["Active"], "X'"],
     Position[
      NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[
       state@"Variables", "X'"],
      y'
      ]],
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, First@state@"VariableRanges"]
  ];
 NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state],
 {state, states}]
(* underflow warnings omitted *)
```

[image]

If the event is changed to `y'[t] > 0`, the first and last solutions run through a long interval in which `y'[t] > 0`.